# swift get location from json

Tags: ios, swift

My code. My problem is that I don't see markers but I'm 100% sure that lat and lng are good. Maybe problem is in conversion. I'm new please help. thanks you

```
                    var point = MKPointAnnotation()
                    let lat = NSString(string: String(row[i]["lat"]))
                    let lng = NSString(string: String(row[i]["lng"]))

                    print(String(row[i]["name"]))

                    point.title = NSString(string: String(row[i]["name"])) as String
                    point.coordinate.latitude = lat.doubleValue
                    point.coordinate.longitude = lng.doubleValue

                    self.mView.addAnnotation(point)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake was conversion, try the below code

```
let location: NSDictionary = [
        "lat": "36.877551",
        "long": "-76.222235",
        "name": "My Location"
    ] 

let point = MKPointAnnotation()
point.coordinate.latitude = CLLocationDegrees(location["lat"] as! String)!
point.coordinate.longitude = CLLocationDegrees(location["long"] as! String)!
point.title = location["name"] as? String 

mapView.addAnnotation(point)
```

Here is full tutorial if you need, http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/mapkit-tutorial-swift-ios8